# Trying to use Webmatrix for contact page in conjunction with Visual Web Developer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webmatrix, visual-web-developer-2010

I'm not a programmer, but I did manage to develop our company site in Visual Web Developer -- and now I'm a full-fledged VWD addict; I'm hooked!

I downloaded Webmatrix the other day and learned a few things in there -- I love that, too.  But I haven't figured out how to integrate Webmatrix into Visual Web Developer.

For instance, if I make a page in Webmatrix, and it's a .cshtml page, can I somehow use it in Visual Web Developer?  If so, how?  Is it (recommended) to do what I'm doing -- make a page in Webmatrix and edit it in VWD, or should the two remain completely independent?

I mean, basically, can the two coexist together, and help each other out?  When I open contact.cshtml in VWD, it shows the source, but offers an error message saying I need a build provider registered for the extension .cshtml, and I can do it with  or something, but it's all Greek to me.

Thank you for your time in reading this, and any and all guidance regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

Jason Weber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the Files workspace, you can see a button at the top right labelled "Visual Studio Launch". Click it and your web site will be opened in VWD 2010, so long as you have SP1 installed.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I tried that, but it gives me some error of some sort.  I just need to reformat and put a new fresh copy of windows on here ... too many errors.  Thanks for taking the time to respond, and I appreciate the advice!